# Can't install metrics plugin on Jenkins with mvn

Tags: maven, jenkins, metrics

I'm trying to install [metrics plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/metrics-plugin) on a Jenkins server and running into some issues following along with the project's README instructions. When I attempt to `release:prepare release:perform -B` I get this:

```
root@:/usr/share/jenkins/metrics-plugin# apache-maven-3.5.3/bin/mvn release:prepare release:perform -B
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The project org.jenkins-ci.plugins:metrics:hpi:3.1.2.12 uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< org.jenkins-ci.plugins:metrics >-------------------
[INFO] Building Metrics Plugin 3.1.2.12
[INFO] --------------------------------[ hpi ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) @ metrics ---
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'scm-tag'
[INFO] Tagging release with the label metrics-3.1.2.12...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /usr/share/jenkins/metrics-plugin && git tag -F /tmp/maven-scm-946969304.commit metrics-3.1.2.12
[INFO] Working directory: /usr/share/jenkins/metrics-plugin
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.721 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-01T22:13:29Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project metrics: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: tag 'metrics-3.1.2.12' already exists
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The apache link is unhelpful. Here is the pom.xml I am using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.37</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>metrics</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.12</version>
  <packaging>hpi</packaging>

  <name>Metrics Plugin</name>
  <description>
    This plugin exposes the Metrics API to Jenkins plugins.
  </description>
  <url>http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Metrics+Plugin</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The MIT license</name>
      <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>stephenconnolly</id>
      <name>Stephen Connolly</name>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>2.2.1</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/jenkinsci/metrics-plugin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/metrics-plugin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/jenkinsci/metrics-plugin</url>
    <tag>metrics-3.1.2.12</tag>
  </scm>

  <properties>
    <jenkins.version>1.580</jenkins.version>
    <metrics.version>3.1.2</metrics.version>
    <java.level>6</java.level>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.findbugs.failure.strict>true</maven.findbugs.failure.strict>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- regular dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
      <version>${metrics.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${metrics.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-healthchecks</artifactId>
      <version>${metrics.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>${metrics.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
      <version>${metrics.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <!-- use the version supplied by jackson2-api -->
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- plugin dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson2-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jenkins dependencies -->
    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.infradna.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>bridge-method-injector</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The README isn't exactly clear, and that will actually tag and release the .hpi itself, not install it on your Jenkins server. Do you have access to the Jenkins web UI or the CLI? If so, how about installing from there instead(https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#from-the-web-ui)

Comment: @NickDeFazio the package I want is, for whatever reason, not available in the "Available" tab in Plugin Manager. I am attempting to do this as a workaround.

Comment: Gotcha. How about manually generating the .hpi and installing from the web ui? Looking at the readme, I'm guessing you can do a mvn clean verify, then via the web UI, select ${metrics plugin project root}/target/metrics.hpi via  (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#from-the-web-ui-2)

Comment: The problem is simply that the tag you are trying to create already exists see `fatal: tag 'metrics-3.1.2.12' already exists..`...